# How to add inline reply button?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

How to append message with an inline button that will do the same action than 
`Right click → Reply`?
Is it possible?

Comment: What should happen when user hits that button under a certain message?

Comment: @IvanVinogradov something like this: https://i.imgur.com/byrnPFE.gif

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an inline button

Pressing the button will send a callback query to your server.

2. React to this CallbackQuery by calling [sendMessage](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage) method with it's parameter `reply_markup` set to `force_reply == true`

Your result will look like [this](https://i.imgur.com/LAyZWG8.mp4).